# How can I sort an array on the first value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that contains strings and arrays. Each string is associated with the arrays that is next to it. For example string 789 is associated with the array, ['111A','222B','333C']. I'm wanting to sort on the string while keeping the array tied to it.

I've tried using `sort()` method which sorts in acceding when I only have strings in my array but when I add the arrays it goes back to the default sort.

```
let myArry = [
  '789', 
  ['111A','222B','333C'], 
  '456',
  ['444E','555F','666G'], 
  '123',
  ['777H','888I','999J']
]

myArray.sort(function(a,b){
return a - b
})
```

At the end of the day I would like the data to look like this.

```
['123', ['777H', '888I','999J'],
'456', ['444E', '555F', '666G'],
'789', ['111A', '222B', '333C']]
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the arrays? Please post the final output you are looking for in the question.

Comment: The `.sort()` method accepts a callback function that can do whatever you need it to do to properly compare values according to your application.

Comment: So what is the code that does not work?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by a pair, sort them and get an flat array back.

```js
var array = ['789', ['111', '222', '333'], '456', ['444', '555', '666'], '123', ['777', '888', '999']],
    result = array
        .reduce((r, v, i) => {
            if (i % 2) r[r.length - 1].push(v);
            else  r.push([v]);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
        .reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, but that gives me the same result.

Comment: sorry about that my the arrays in my array look more like this, ```['801A56','456T78','458R454']```. Again sorry for the poor example.

Comment: for this problem, you may add another question (with an attempt).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array to keep the 2 elements together for each String found, after that you sort by the strings and apply a concat to get an array like the initial, but ordered by strings:

```js
let myArray = [
      '789',
      ['111', '222', '333'],
      '456',
      ['444', '555', '666'],
      '123',
      ['777', '888', '999'],
];
    
const orderMyArrayByTheStrings = (myArray) => {
    
  const myArrayWithArrays = myArray
        .reduce((acc, el, index, array) => {
          if (!(el instanceof Array)) {
            return acc.push([el, array[index + 1]]) && acc;
          } else {
            return acc;
          }
        }, [])

  const myArraySortedByStrings = myArrayWithArrays.sort((a, b) => {
          return a[0] - b[0];
        })
    
  return [].concat.apply([], myArraySortedByStrings)
    
}
    
console.log(orderMyArrayByTheStrings(myArray))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can define the sort function where you can change items type - for example toString()

```
let myArray = [
    '789', 
    ['111','222','333'], 
    '456',
    ['444','555','666'], 
    '123',
    ['777','888','999']
];
myArray.sort((left,right)=>{
    if(left.toString() < right.toString()) {
        return -1;
    } else if(left.toString() > right.toString()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```